# How to determine cause of EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift

I am in the process of breaking up a monolithic framework in my project into a bunch of smaller Swift packages. This is mostly a matter of moving declarations out of the framework and into one of the packages, then changing the `import`s to use the packages.

I have run into an issue with my tests crashing with `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x30)`. The stack trace is here:

```
MyUnitTests`StubNetworkClient.__allocating_init(baseURL:):
    0x111b3b0d4 <+0>:  sub    sp, sp, #0x30             ; =0x30 
    0x111b3b0d8 <+4>:  stp    x20, x19, [sp, #0x10]
    0x111b3b0dc <+8>:  stp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x20]
    0x111b3b0e0 <+12>: add    x29, sp, #0x20            ; =0x20 
    0x111b3b0e4 <+16>: str    x0, [sp, #0x8]
    0x111b3b0e8 <+20>: mov    x0, x20
->  0x111b3b0ec <+24>: ldr    w8, [x0, #0x30]
    0x111b3b0f0 <+28>: mov    x1, x8
    0x111b3b0f4 <+32>: ldrh   w8, [x0, #0x34]
    0x111b3b0f8 <+36>: mov    x2, x8
    0x111b3b0fc <+40>: bl     0x111bea0dc               ; symbol stub for: swift_allocObject
    0x111b3b100 <+44>: mov    x20, x0
    0x111b3b104 <+48>: ldr    x0, [sp, #0x8]
    0x111b3b108 <+52>: bl     0x111b3b11c               ; NetworkClientTestSupport.StubNetworkClient.init(baseURL: Foundation.URL) -> NetworkClientTestSupport.StubNetworkClient<C> at StubNetworkClient.swift:98
    0x111b3b10c <+56>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x20]
    0x111b3b110 <+60>: ldp    x20, x19, [sp, #0x10]
    0x111b3b114 <+64>: add    sp, sp, #0x30             ; =0x30 
    0x111b3b118 <+68>: ret
```

If I'm reading this correctly, it says that this is crashing in library code even before it enters my initializer.

It's almost impossible for me to create a minimal test case, but I was hoping that somebody may have suggestions on what I could do to troubleshoot or solve it.

This is Xcode 13.2.1 targeting the simulator on a M1 Macbook Pro.

Followup:

I removed all of the packages from the linking phase for both the target and the test target, then re-added them one-by-one until it built, and now it doesn’t crash in the tests. So it was some kind of issue with the linker.

Comment: Are you force unwrapping the URL you are passing?  Are you sure it isn't `nil`

Comment: `StubNetworkClient.swift:98` line 98, what's there?

Comment: I am not force unwrapping the URL. This happens on every call no matter what URL I pass to the initialize.

Comment: Line 98 is where the initializer is declared. It's not a runnable line of code.